# In Hg, how to ignore a directory which contain some already tracked directories and files?

Tags: mercurial

In Hg, how to ignore a directory recursively if some of its subdirectories and contained files are already tracked?  I'd like to keep them in my file system but don't version control them.  I don't want to remove the directory from the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hg forget dir_name/` to stop tracking directory called `dir_name` recursively.

More info on `hg forget`:

```
hg forget [OPTION]... FILE...

forget the specified files on the next commit

    Mark the specified files so they will no longer be tracked after the next
    commit.

    This only removes files from the current branch, not from the entire
    project history, and it does not delete them from the working directory.

    To undo a forget before the next commit, see "hg add".

    Examples:

    - forget newly-added binary files:

        hg forget "set:added() and binary()"

    - forget files that would be excluded by .hgignore:

        hg forget "set:hgignore()"

    Returns 0 on success.

options:

 -I --include PATTERN [+] include names matching the given patterns
 -X --exclude PATTERN [+] exclude names matching the given patterns
    --mq                  operate on patch repository
```

Comment: Also iirc other clients should copy those files somewhere, because on pull-update they will be deleted

Comment: Really!?  That's so dangerous.  Why Kai doesn't warn me!?

Comment: @user001 I would say it is the expected behaviour when want to ignore a directory. I don't also see this is any more dangerous than any other type of commits -- you can always revert to previous changeset when everything was still there, which is the point of using version control in the first place. In case the other clients need to keep them these files, they can also execute `hg forget dir_name`.

Comment: But I said explicitly "I'd like to keep them in my file system but don't version control them."  I do want to keep these in my local file system.  After `hg forget dir`, what next do I do to get everything sync'ed and still have the dir kept in my local file system?

Comment: @user: some notes besides. First of all, mercurial doesn't track directories, but the files in it. That may be an important thought to keep in mind. Second, I think the solution of Kay is just fine. If you want to keep your files and want Mercurial to ignore them, well, just tell Mercurial to do so. Add the files to the ignore list right after forgetting them as Kay explained. Maybe this is just one additional step to the solution you want. I assume you're tracking the .hgignore file of course ;)

Comment: @user001 yes, the `dir` in `hg forget dir` will kept in your local system. It's just that after you push this changeset, the **other** users will get this `dir` deleted on **their** local machine when they update.